# Weed, sex and gym

Tags: gym, sex

I have very simple question - Is it bad to have sex and/or get high after gym? How those activities affect gains and mass growth?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The science of fitness is not the most advanced field. Many things we do not know and basically all studies that I've seen debating what has minor influences on muscle growth were inconclusive or flawed. Now you are asking about two that are really hard to look into. Few subjects are able follow a tight weed or sex schedule over several months and even if, there are many problems with that. Some questions don't have answers. Are you a competitive body builder? Listen to your coach or fellow body builders, not strangers. If you aren't, 5g muscle more or less a month simply doesn't matter

Comment: I'm not professional body builder but I'm curious...

Comment: The only thing we can say at this point is that I wouldn't worry. If weed or sex affects muscle repair and recovery, it is only to such a negligible degree that you won't actually notice any difference.

Comment: Your question simply asks how they affect muscle growth. And not whether they affect or not, or by what degree they affect. I have therefore answered your question below on how they affect muscle growth. Do mention if you need more details on any section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two factors you mentioned actually have an influence on your central nervous system (CNS) and hence your performance therefore growth. They are not as influential as other factors like food and rest, but are influential enough for those that are involved heavily in the two.

Before answering your questions it's worth noting that the CNS is involved big time in heavy exercises, endurance exercises, etc. Therefore apart from your muscles requiring rest and repair, your CNS also requires rest and recovery. This means it should be considered in the meaning of recovery (which influences performance and growth). If it does not recover you may not be able to perform as well in the gym (regarding concentration, endurance, strength).

**1• Cannabis smoke will definitely affect your growth and performance**. **The quality of blood going to the muscles is decreased**. Your haemoglobin will preferably bind to carbon monoxide than oxygen. Oxygen is required during exercise and also in recovery. Some oxygen is stored in the muscles too I believe, for use during exercise when blood oxygen is not enough, so if that is reduced, so will your muscular performance and/therefore growth. There are other effects like the quality of your lungs and your ability to dissolve oxygen from the air.

There are studies showing that **[cannabis can reduce testosterone levels](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6090909)**. Testosterone is highly influential in muscle growth. Its reduction will see a reduction in growth most likely.

Cannabis has a direct effect on the CNS. It induces a `feel good effect`. After those effects wears off, you may experience depression like feelings, which may indirectly influence your growth in that you may not eat as well, you may not exercise as well and you may not sleep as well, among other things. Whether the feel good effect helps you sleep better is also a personal variable to consider. If you sleep better then its possibly an advantage, if not its possible a disadvantage to your growth.

Cannabis's effect on the CNS also means the CNS may possibly need some time and resources to return to its 'healthy'/'normal' state where it can support daily activities and on top of that your weight exercises in a normal way. If you don't rest your CNS enough, you may continue to experience the feelings of lethargy, lack of determination, tiredness, and depression as your CNS hasn't fully recovered, meaning you will not perform as well in the gym, therefore your potential growth may be reduced.

Cannabis also helps with reducing swelling and pain. Is that going to help you exercise better in the gym? If it does then look forward to possible better growth, given all other factors are provided (nutrition, rest, etc). Though you may also be injuring yourself by hiding the pain and continuing to use the muscles. Is the reduction in pain and swelling going to help you sleep better? If so so then you will recover, repair and have better growth, again, given other factors are in sufficient quantities/levels. If you get dependant on these effects and therefore can't sleep well without cannabis then your growth may be reduced. It's all circumstantial.

**2• Copulation (sex) heavily involves the nervous system, muscles too**. Those feelings felt during the act are induced through hormones and effected through the CNS. Climax and a happy ending at the end of copulation also heavily involve the CNS, thats why the individuals involved feel tired and sleepy afterwards. Muscles involved in copulation are varied, so your muscles that require rest may be used during copulation and may be further exhausted past the recovery required before their next exercise, maybe not. All circumstantial.

A male can use up-to 300 calories during sex. **If you require 3600 calories per day for a very active lifestyle requiring muscle growth, 300 calories of sex is equivalent to two hours worth of calories**, or one twelfth of your total calorie intake. If you are religious about your caloric intake then this value is significant, it can easily tip you under your target, and stop you from growing more muscle. Your body can start to break other muscles for repair damaged ones.

The effect of copulation on growth is circumstantial- Are you going to eat well, and rest well to counter the effects, and possibly have them work to your advantage? Is your nutrition and rest as a male enough to produce more sperm, repair and grow your muscles without breaking others down? Are you not going to rest enough and in return affect recovery and repair, hence affecting gym performance and/therefore growth?

The effects of cannabis are more indirect but still worth noting for heavy or regular users. Are you going to take it enough that you CNS is not in its normal healthy state? Then yes, your recovery will be affected, and therefore growth (indirect).

Resources:

- [Cannabis effect on growth](https://www.livestrong.com/article/148436-the-effects-of-cannabis-on-muscle-growth/)
- [Cannabis effects on body.](https://www.healthline.com/health/addiction/marijuana/effects-on-body#2)
- [Respiratory effects of cannabis.](http://adai.uw.edu/marijuana/factsheets/respiratoryeffects.htm)
- [Cannabis on Testosterone](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6090909)
- [Calories during sex](https://www.menshealth.com/sex-women/a19537023/sex-workout/)